wsdl generation with ant task fails with jakarta packages instead of javax
I am trying to build wsdl for my web service using ant task\wsgen.bat, which is working fine when I use javax packages in my web service class, and giving below exception. When I use jakarta instead of javax in name space and annotations for web service class.
 [exec] Caused by: com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.ModelerException: A web service endpoint could not be found

The above error is coming when I run my web xml in eclipse. I have placed required jakarta jars in classpath. Could you please help me what could be the issue here?
I am using wsgen in ant task to call wsgen.bat.
wsdl:
     [exec] Apr 10, 2024 10:50:27 AM javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder find
     [exec] WARNING: Using deprecated META-INF/services mechanism with non-standard property: javax.xml.soap.MetaFactory. Property javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory should be used instead.
     [exec] Apr 10, 2024 10:50:27 AM javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder find
     [exec] WARNING: Using deprecated META-INF/services mechanism with non-standard property: javax.xml.soap.MetaFactory. Property javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory should be used instead.
     [exec] Apr 10, 2024 10:50:27 AM javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder find
     [exec] WARNING: Using deprecated META-INF/services mechanism with non-standard property: javax.xml.soap.MetaFactory. Property javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory should be used instead.
     [exec] Apr 10, 2024 10:50:27 AM javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder find
     [exec] WARNING: Using deprecated META-INF/services mechanism with non-standard property: javax.xml.soap.MetaFactory. Property javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory should be used instead.
     [exec] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.ModelerException: A web service endpoint could not be found
     [exec]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.invocationHelper(JavacTaskImpl.java:168)
     [exec]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
     [exec]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
     [exec]     at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool.buildModel(Unknown Source)
     [exec]     at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool.run(Unknown Source)
     [exec]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [exec]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
     [exec]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [exec]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
     [exec]     at com.sun.tools.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:153)
     [exec]     at com.sun.tools.ws.WsGen.main(WsGen.java:56)
     [exec] Caused by: com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.ModelerException: A web service endpoint could not be found
     [exec]     at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceAp.processError(WebServiceAp.java:238)
     [exec]     at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceAp.process(WebServiceAp.java:197)
     [exec]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1023)
     [exec]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:939)
     [exec]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1267)
     [exec]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1382)
     [exec]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1234)
     [exec]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:916)
     [exec]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
     [exec]     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.invocationHelper(JavacTaskImpl.java:152)
     [exec]     ... 10 more

I tried using wsgen task\taskdef instead of wsgen bat, then I am getting class not found exception, but my service class name \ path is same in javax and jakarta implementation.
